# Adding a NewLine Character to a Textbox in an ActiveX control in C#

Tags: c#, activex

I'm trying to add a newline character to a string that I want to print out to a status box in my ActiveX control.  The status box is a multiline TextBox. I've tried adding "\r\n" to the string, I've tried add System.Environment.NewLine to the string, but nothing seems to work. Not sure what else to trying.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: is it multiline or just showing linewrapping? it also depends what they have chosen to make visible to you

Comment: It's just linewrapping (not applying the NewLine).

Comment: perhaps then its not properly multiline....

Answer (score 1):

Environment.NewLine returns a platform-specific string for beginning a new line, which should be:

- "\r\n" (\u000D\u000A) for Windows
- "\n" (\u000A) for Unix

Or you could try to use StringBuilder with the following:

```
sb.AppendLine(someText);
sb.AppendLine("");
sb.AppendLine(moreText);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll trying adding the characters in Unicode then I'll try using StringBuilder